# How to enable app on apple app store to view-able on browser?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

This is the first time I upload an app to apple app store. After weeks for reviewing, finally, I get my app listed on apple app store. But the problem is, now seems like my app app-store page is only viewable from iTunes. When I try to open it in a browser, it will shows "Connecting to the iTunes Store...". Why is it my app can't be the view from the browser? Why did another app can? How to fix it?

Comment: did your review process just finish? i think it takes like up to a day for it to propagate fully, so maybe just give it a while

Comment: It's viewable on the browser. Can you edit your question and add the link?

Comment: @Fonix Thanks for your comment. It's been 24 hours by now, but still unable open on the browser. Btw, here's my app link (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/teaspoon-food-restaurants/id1072288534). I don't know you can open it or not because I have set it to distribute only on my country. Thank you.

Comment: hmm strange, im not sure then, you may want to just contact apple support directly then

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It seems, you cannot fully predict the behavior of an app store link for a certain user. You being redirected doesn't mean other people will be redirected right away as well. Your app's country/language availability, users' app store region and language settings, the specificity of the app store link (which has optional components and alternative styles), and the browser cache all seem to have a say.

Added details: After experimenting with this a lot, it seems to me that the behavior of the link (or rather the response from the Apple server to requesting it) depends on the language/country version being requested, my own current country/language defined in iTunes/my app store account, plus some caching issues. So, whether a preview page is shown in the browser, or iTunes is attempted to be opened right away depends on several factors and doesn't always have the same result (for different users). In fact, two consecutive attempts to open the same URL can have different redirect behavior.

I noticed that a full app store link like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote/id361285480 more likely leads to the preview web page, if the app is available in the language/country referenced ("us" in the example) and there is no prior request cached in which I clicked through to the app in iTunes. If the app isn't available in the referenced location, or any other information is missing in the link for the Apple server to identify a particular language version on the preview website, or there is cached data that makes Apple confident enough to redirect you to iTunes directly (or it's Friday 13th and the moon is right behind the sun by pure chance...) then you may see a redirect instead.

For posting app store links in the likes of Facebook, [Apple's app linker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com) seems to produce URLs with the nicest preview snippets (and not: "Connecting to the iTunes store"), when putting in the right country. So, these generated URLs seem to be most complete/specific.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is intended for a specific region, AppStore connect will still give you a  URL with .../us/... in it. Changing it to the respective local region seems to fix the problem for me.

For an example,
given URL: https://apps.apple.com/**us**/app/yourcompany/id123456

If the app is for Norway region, change the URL to: https://apps.apple.com/**no**/app/yourcompany/id123456